# Customizing complex layout with data driven page?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, layouts, definition-query, strip-map

Main Conditions: It should be in one MXD document.

What i have:
1 line feature (*with definition queries*), 1 polygon feature (*with definition queries*) *this is one as example in fact number of layers will be more*
, 1 Strip Map Index Features (**SMIF**) (*with defenition queries*).
**DF1** - Data Driven Page, **DF2** - Extent Obj1/Obj2, **DF3** - Extent of All objects. On the **DF2** To show what page now is showing i use *Page Definition* for two copies of a layer **SMIF**.

To export map i follow this way:

1. in Definition Query Manager manually choose query **Obj1** for each layers, including Strip Map Index Layer.
2. refresh Data Driven Pages
3. Activate **DF2** Pan to spatial Bookmark "**Obj1_Extent_bookmark1**"
4. Export map to PDF
5. in Definition Query Manager manually choose query **Obj2** for each layers, including Strip Map Index Layer.
6. refresh Data Driven Pages
7. Activate **DF2** Pan to spatial Bookmark "**Obj2_Extent_bookmark2**"
8. Export map to PDF

Is it possible to automate the definition queries selection and spatial bookmarks choosing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even if you can, I think it would be a lot easier to step away from Data Driven Pages for these requirements, and to instead use ArcPy to cursor through your index layer to gain much more control.

Comment: @PolyGeo Can you show me a code sample?

Comment: Although it is for ArcGIS Pro, rather than ArcMap, and not free, the coding patterns used in this [Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/map-automation-using-arcpy-for-arcgis-pro/) originally came from and are easily applied back to the older architecture.